# How to remove an element from a Jquery object

Tags: jquery

After doing the following: `$hold=$('<div>').load('page.php #somediv)` I'm trying to remove an element in that html called `removediv` depending on the value of a cookie. I've tried:

```
if ($.cookie('mycookie') !== null){
$hold=$hold.not('#removediv');
}else{
document.cookie = "mycookie=1;expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2020 23:59:59 UTC; path=/"
}
$('#divtwo').html($hold);
```

But the `removediv` element always shows up, even when the cookie is set. I've also tried `$hold.find('#removediv').remove()`, but that also didn't work.

Any ideas?

EDIT: The $hold html looks like this:

```
<div>
 <div id="somediv">
  <div id="removediv" class="stuff"></div>
  <div id="okdiv" class="stuff"></div>
  <div id="okdiv" class="stuff"></div>
  <div id="okdiv" class="stuff"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you display the relavent HTML of page.php?  Are you sure the id is correct?  And that it only exists once?

Comment: @scott.korin Just edited the question with the html.

Comment: `$hold=$hold.not('#removediv');` won't affect the DOM. It simply creates a new jQuery result set and stores it in the variable called $hold.

Comment: @tcovo but I am then using the new `$hold` to populate the `divtwo` html.

Comment: Calling `$hold.find('#removediv').remove()` should do the right thing. However, the `.load` method initiates an _asynchronous_ ajax request - is your code being executed after the response is received (i.e. in the "complete" callback) or is it possible this code is being called too early?

Comment: @Phil, regarding `$hold=$hold.not('#removediv');`: $hold is a jQuery object which initially contains a single element, the `div`, and filtering that result with `not('#removediv')` will result in the same set (still just the `div`). Understand that `.not()` only filters a jQuery result set; it does not modify the elements inside the set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my best guess at how to make this work. Use `remove` to remove `removediv` from the html fragment, and put the code in the "complete" callback of the `load` method:

```
$hold = $('<div>').load('page.php #somediv', function(response, status, xhr) {
    if ($.cookie('mycookie') !== null){
        $hold.find('#removediv').remove();
    } else {
        document.cookie = "mycookie=1;expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2020 23:59:59 UTC; path=/"
    }
    $('#divtwo').html($hold);
});
```

Comment: tcovo, the asynchronous request was indeed the problem, and I solved it as per your instructions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing that in callback function like this

```
$('<div>').load('page.php #somediv', function(data) {
  $hold = data;

  if ($.cookie('mycookie') !== null){
    $hold.find('#removediv').remove();
   } else {
    document.cookie = "mycookie=1;expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2020 23:59:59 UTC; path=/"
   }
   $('#divtwo').html($hold);


});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is why things don't work with your example:

- `load()` is an async call, so you need to continue your treatment only when the call ended
- `$hold.find('#removediv').remove()` will only select the div, not actually remove it

For your code o work you need, to make use of the [`callback`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) and the [`end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/), like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#l").click(function() {

    var url = 'b.htm';

    $("#content").load(url + " #somediv", function(data) {

      var allHtml = $(data),
          newHtml = allHtml.find("#removediv").remove().end();

      console.log(newHtml.html());
    });

  });
});
</script>
```

assuming that you have a file with this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Stackoverflow example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>

  <a href="#" id="l">load content</a>
  <div id="content">Empty</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and `b.htm` has

```
<div>
 <div id="somediv">
  <div id="removediv" class="stuff">A</div>
  <div id="okdiv" class="stuff">B</div>
  <div id="okdiv" class="stuff">C</div>
  <div id="okdiv" class="stuff">D</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

the output would be (In Firefox as Chrome blocks the call for `b.htm` as a cross domain call as it's a local file)

[image]

output show:

```
console.log('data');
console.log(data);  
console.log('newHtml');
console.log(newHtml.html());
```

> [Example is on my **Dropbox**](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/t46rp4i0nxbdl6h/d8bRIOKOtg) if you need to see both files.

---

using your own code:

```
$(function() {

    $('<div/>').load('page.php #somediv', function(data) {

        // 'data' has the page.php #somediv part
        var allHtml = $(data);

        if ($.cookie('mycookie') !== null)
            allHtml = allHtml.find("#removediv").remove().end();
        else
            document.cookie = "mycookie=1;expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2020 23:59:59 UTC; path=/"

        $('#divtwo').html(allHtml);
    });
});
```

Comment: download the files I exposed and give it a try then, if you're so sure of yourself :)